# Connection between Ionic Frontend and NodeJS server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, model-view-controller, mobile, ionic-framework

I've been trying these past couple days to connect an android app made with Ionic Framework with an SQL Database. After some research I understood that between my frontend and backend I need a `RESTful API` that will help the communication between those two. So since I was building my app with Ionic I started making the server with NodeJS. I made the connection between MySQL and NodeJS, just a very simple hello world script which i'll enter below.

```
//Setup
var db = require('./db');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();



app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
  if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
    res.status(200).end();
  } else {
    next();
  }
});



//Config
function handle_database(req, res) {

  db.connect(db.MODE_PRODUCTION, function (err) { //connect to database
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected");
  })


  res.send("hello world");
 // db.select('*', 'enikio1.customer', 'FirstName = "Nick"', res);

}


app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  handle_database(req, res);
});

//Listen,Hey
app.listen(3000);
console.log("App listening on port 3000");
```

But I can't get a response from the Server when I'm in my app. I used Angular's Ajax to get the response and just show my response to a string but nothing happens. For some reason I cant get the response from the server. To clarify some stuff, my MySQL server is hosted on Azure, but i run (for now) my NodeJS server on localhost. I run the frontend to an android emulator ( Standard one of the Android SDK ). I also have the server side and the frontend in different locations, not sure if that's a problem but every tutorial i have seen making a web app with Node and angular has them in the same workplace, I have them on a seperate because it's supposed to be a mobile app. Here is my controller.

```
 .controller('AccountCtrl', function ($scope, $state,$http,$ionicPopup, $rootScope) {

    $scope.signin = function() //signin is in the submit button
    { 
        console.log("Some")
            str="http://localhost:3000";
            data = {};
            datastr = "";
            $http.get(str)
            .success(function (response){ 
                // data = response[0].Email;
                // $scope.data.email = data;    

                datastr = response;
                $scope.server = datastr; //server is a label 

            })
    } 
    });
```

Now I'm clearly really new to web/app development and don't know what's going on, I just really wanted to start learning AngularJS, cordova framework and all that plus now I also have the chance to learn NodeJS which seems super useful, but this problem has me really confused. Based on what I understand when the app goes to my path it should get a response which i save to datastr and then i pass it to `$scope.server` which is a label so `hello world` would print. But nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can run the app on Browser with ``ionic serve`` and check for any error message. Seems like a ``CORS`` issue. check out http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Comment: I wasn't running it from the Browser to avoid CORS in the first place, but ill try it as soon as possible :)

Comment: So apparently when i edited the `ionic.project` which is now renamed to `ionic.config.json` for anyone who might wanna know in the future, with the proxy I had an error. A comment in the link you provided suggested a chrome extension `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin` which actually allowed me to see that a connection is indeed happening. I found it out by first,    `console.log (res.send("hello world"));` which was actually json, so i made it to string and now it shows me `[Object Object]` in the log whenever i go to my localhost:3000 or whenever i click the submit in the app.

Comment: So that totally helped me out, I was finally able to make a select, maybe write it again as an answer so i can check it? @raj

Comment: I have added it as an answer. By the way , what was the exact reason for this problem? I dont work on node js. Usually I add wild card access for ``CORS`` in my backend (Rails) while developing.

Comment: I think it was just `CORS` not letting the two communicate, once I allowed CORS everything run fine, after that the only reason the response didn't show was a stupid error of mine in the html file. But yeah now i can do everything just fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the app on Browser with `ionic serve` and check for any error messages. Seems like a `CORS` issue. Check out http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/ for more info on `CORS` in Ionic

Answer (score 0):

you should replace the localhost with the ip address of your server in str="http://localhost:3000" and they should be in the same network

Comment: The NodeJS server runs on localhost/127.0.0.1 in port 3000, in the emulator it doesn't run on the server. running it through browser and enabling CORS i achieved connection ( as you said they are on the same server now) although now it seems that the only reason i can't progress is my understanding of the whole connectivity, responses and requests. But i'll figure it out :) Although it is kind of wierd, why would a mobile app need to be in the same server? Shouldn't the app just be able to take data from a path just with an internet connection?